# Is it possible to have a "New Terminal Here" option in finder, similar to the "New Terminal at Folder" when you right click on a folder?

Tags: terminal, finder

It's annoying to have to go up one folder, find the folder I was just in, then right click it to open a terminal there. I'm wondering if it's possible to show an option to open a new terminal in the folder I'm currently in from finder? (I'm running Monterey)

Comment: Presumably you're using Icon View? If you use Command Up arrow, that will take you to the parent folder, but with the current folder selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not done so already, instruct the Finder application to show the path bar. The current folder is shown on this path bar. You can right click on the current folder and select to open a new Terminal at folder. See image below.

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks!